# In experience, what distro of Linux is ideal for SPO

Tags: spo, linux

I'm at a point where I'll be running an SPO. I am curious from the current SPOs what version of Linux do they recommend. I've practiced setting up a pool on ubuntu and mint.

Comment: Ubuntu is the most widely used OS. However, any Linux distribution should be fine. Windows is best avoided.

Comment: This is too subjective to be on topic in my opinion. IOHK offers a wide range of support, seemingly equal (for Linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installation of Cardano nodes is done by compiling [the source codes](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases), so any Linux distribution can host your node. However, the majority of the "SPO" community is primarily experimenting with [Ubuntu LTS](https://www.ubuntu-fr.org/download/) (documentation, how-to, Q&A etc.) in [the official forum](https://forum.cardano.org/c/staking-delegation/setup-a-stake-pool/158). So if you're new to exploring the Cardano ecosystem, you might want to you start with the Ubuntu distrib in order to benefit from existing feedbacks.

Moreover, if you want an excellent step-by-step tutorial to set up your pool, I recommend the [guide "How to build a Cardano Stake Pool" from CoinCashew](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node).

Good luck!